# Introducing a Java stats package to an application?

Tags: java, tomcat, statistics

I currently have a web application and wish to add certain statistics to the site. These statistics would be **in addition** to web statistics.

I can easily log certain events to a file via log4j. Is there something I can add that will investigate the data and format it in a human readable way (chart or table)?

The application is running in tomcat.

Comment: What do you mean be "correctly"?

Comment: What kind of statistics? What do you mean by *normal* web statistics? Isn't Google Analytics an option?

Comment: I've updated with clarification. We use Google analytics already, but want to record extra that Google analytics doesn't record, not related to specific web pages (we have AJAX elements). I guess the fact that a web application is irrelevant except that it describes the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We log events for our web-shop in our database. Something like this

```
ID-----USER-----EVENTTYPE-----DATE
```

Then it's easy to create graphs with Google Chart showing logins, orders created, payments done with visa vs mastercard, files download last 30 days etc..

Comment: Thanks, this is closest to the approach I was considering. How do you parse the data? Do you have to build SQL for each new event (ie what if someone wanted to see a new chart, "logins by day")?

Comment: The eventype is just a number, so you can have one method taking two values; int eventype and int numberOfDays, and with a little group by-sql you get how many logins you have the last N day

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try JMX and a console that will let you see values at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an MBean and view it through jmx console.  Or add a class that handles the logging, and format it, and then in Log4J you could output that class only to it's own log file.  You could then write a parser on that file, and view it via a webpage if necessary.